# nginx (nginx/1.10.0 ) not working after ubuntu OS upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ubuntu-14.04, rhel

I upgraded ubuntu and after up-gradation, example.com (name changed) stopped working and giving below error. I am using nginx (nginx/1.10.0 ) and ubuntu (release 16.04). The whole setup is on AWS EC2

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

Below are contents from nginx error log

```
[error] 1201#1201: *27 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 171.76.106.51, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "public IP", referrer: "https://publicIP/"
```

Below is nginx.conf file

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";



    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

nginx sites-enabled default has symlink to sites-available default and below is the content

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Another nginx conf file

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;
  # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

When I am doing http://localhost:3000/ it says connection refused

```
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3000... failed: Connection refused.
```

When I am doing "wget www.google.com" its says connected

Can you please help here ?

Comment: Can you share your nginx dummy config?

Comment: @SahilGulati I have pasted nginx.conf file, please take a look

Comment: no, i am talking about your sites-enable/default.conf. Please share that.

Comment: @SahilGulati I have pasted the content of sites-enabled default

Comment: Now my question is do you want `HTML` file or `php` file to execute?

Comment: Tell me what you are getting when you are hitting your IP address?

Comment: @SahilGulati when I am typing https://example.com I am getting "502 Bad Gateway". Even I am doing http://localhost:3000/ it says connection refused

Comment: okay let me check. you configuration

Comment: do you some other configurations? for virtual hosts?

Comment: @SahilGulati I have pasted the file, please have a look

Comment: So problem is server running on this `http://localhost:3000/`is not responding

Comment: @SahilGulati yes.It says connection refused. I have also pasted the nginx error logs

Comment: What is server_name example.com ,whether it is related to upstream and abc.com? what do you want to run on that 3000port? did you reread and reload the nginx and did you checked the status of nginx?did you tested the nginx whether it is configured well using sudo nginx -t

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi I have corrected my post as a part of confidentiality, I renamed the actual DNS. So example.com is website I am hosting using ngnix as web server. nginx -t says "its successful". docker proxy runs on 3000 port

Comment: @Dave did you redirected you DNS properly to that IP?

Comment: @ShivkumarKondi yes via ROute53. Do we need do something at OS level too ? I am not experienced person with nginx so please bear with my  questions

Comment: Its fine. we mostly use nginx with supervisor to have control over our setups/programs.

Comment: Can you post your log files from `/var/nginx`? Also ensure nginx is running smoothly using `sudo service nginx status`.